# How to exclude specific libraries by default in maven?

Tags: java, spring, maven, frameworks, maven-module

I'm writing some kind of framework, and within want to provide a specific feature that uses `lucene` (take lucene as an example of any feature here).

So in my framework I definitely have to `maven` include the lucene library as `dependency` to be able to build the feature upon.

Now I don't want to create a submodule for every feature, but rather have everything packed in a single jar library. And if the user wants to use the lucene-feature, he might activate it using `Spring`, and would also have to include the lucene libs with maven.

But how can I achive this? So far I have the lucene library in my framework, and if I use this as a dependency, automatically the lucene libs are imported too, even if the feature is not used. How can I prevent this?

Comment: The Maven scope `provided` is not what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the Maven scope `provided` would solve your problem :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
    <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

From the [maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) :

> - **compile**
>
> This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile
>   dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project.
>   Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.
>
> - **provided**
>
> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a
>   container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when
>   building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would
>   set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to
>   scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This
>   scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is
>   not transitive.

In your case you do not expect a container to provide the dependency but the user of your framework to include it (if he needs to).